# Write Api for Eventbrite?

Tags: api, eventbrite

Is there a way for my user to access their eventbrite account, and post events from my web app?

Comment: If you like the answer, please select it. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as a matter of fact:

http://developer.eventbrite.com/

and

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/getting-started/